# How to block a user from executing select queries on a table in Db2?

Tags: sql, linux, db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I have a database 'SAMPLE' in which I need to block a user 'DB2ADMIN' from executing

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG
```

I already tried

```
REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG FROM USER DB2ADMIN
```

I get error SQL0556N and message "DB2ADMIN does not hold this privilege", which means it shouldn't have worked in first place.

Still I am able to get select query results when I log in with that account and execute above query. Can someone suggest a way out to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query provide you information on why your `DB2ADMIN` user has `SELECT` or `CONTROL` privileges (if any) on the `SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG` view.

```
SELECT  
  P.PRIVILEGE, U.AUTHID, U.AUTHIDTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P
CROSS JOIN (VALUES 'DB2ADMIN') A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE 
(
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.AUTHID AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.AUTHIDTYPE
WHERE P.OBJECTSCHEMA = 'SYSIBMADM' AND P.OBJECTNAME = 'DBMCFG' 
AND P.PRIVILEGE IN ('SELECT', 'CONTROL');
```

The following query provide you information on why your `DB2ADMIN` user has one of DATAACCESS, DBADM, SQLADM, SECADM or ACCESSCTRL authorities (if any) sufficient to select from this view. 
**Update**
Note, that the `Authorization list` for [SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022029.html) is not correct. It's one of the system catalog views, and one having [SECADM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0021054.html) or [ACCESSCTRL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0053933.html) database authority has an access to this view. So, we need to check both these user authorities in addition.

```
SELECT 
  P.GRANTEE, P.GRANTEETYPE
, P.DATAACCESSAUTH, P.DBADMAUTH, P.SQLADMAUTH, P.SECURITYADMAUTH, P.ACCESSCTRLAUTH
FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH P
CROSS JOIN (VALUES 'DB2ADMIN') A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE 
(
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.GRANTEE AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.GRANTEETYPE
WHERE 'Y' IN (P.DATAACCESSAUTH, P.DBADMAUTH, P.SQLADMAUTH, P.SECURITYADMAUTH, P.ACCESSCTRLAUTH);
```

Comment: Both of them return empty results, thanks for the effort to create query though

Comment: What's the Db2 version you use?

Comment: latest version (11.5)

Comment: Open a Case with IBM support then. If both these queries above return empty result on `DB2ADMIN`, then this user must not have an ability to select from this view according to the documentation.

Comment: Dude if this doesn't workout then can you tell me how to create a user with no privileges or authorities to execute select queries on any tables in Windows 10, even that would cover my purpose, that is to test a user without select table permission

Comment: I can't suggest you anything else except these 2 select statements. Just create another account in your OS, and run these queries using this account name and a table / view name in objectschema and objectname. If you get the same result, when the result is empty, but this user still has an ability to select from this table / view, then it's either a defect or you do something wrong (use different account to run select, for example).

Comment: @DivikShrivastava I've updated the answer. Please, check it.

Comment: A big thanks to you dude, ACCESSCTRL was it, it was the authority that needed removal. Faith on Stackoverflow restored!!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation for the [administrative view (not table) SYIDBMADM.DBMCFG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022029.html). It states the following:

> One of the following authorizations is required:
>
> - SELECT privilege on the DBMCFG administrative view
> - CONTROL privilege on the DBMCFG administrative view
> - DATAACCESS authority
> - DBADM authority
> - SQLADM authority

So that user in question might not have **SELECT** privilege, but may have **DBADM** authority. Given the user name, I might guess correctly that is the case. Revoke **DBADM** authority from that user and test again.

If that does not help, try to find out more about that user(id). Use the procedures [AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021976.html), [AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html) and [PRIVILEGES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021978.html) to obtain security-related information.

Comment: I removed everything as stated above, I used `REVOKE DATAACCESS ON DATABASE FROM USER DB2ADMIN` (and same for other two authorities) yet I am unable to do it.

Comment: I added more tips.